# plot confusion matrix as stacked bar chart with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, confusion-matrix

I have a confusion matrix that I want to plot as stacked bar chart with `ggplot2`.

```
# confusion matrix
conf <- structure(c(3015, 672, 874, 3217, 0.224736436101826, 0.1727950629982
), .Dim = 2:3, .Dimnames = list(c("FALSE", "TRUE"), c("FALSE", 
"TRUE", "class.error")))

conf
#       FALSE TRUE class.error
# FALSE  3015  874   0.2247364
# TRUE    672 3217   0.1727951
```

I tried reshaping it using `tidyr`:

```
conf <- as.data.frame(rf$confusion)
conf$actual <- row.names(conf)
conf <- tidyr::pivot_longer(conf, c(`FALSE`, `TRUE`))
conf$prediction <- conf$name
```

and then plotting using:

```
ggplot(conf, aes(x = actual, fill = prediction)) + geom_bar(position = "fill")
```

---

actual output:

[image]

---

But there are several issues:

1. The bars should have the height according to the `value` column of my confusion matrix
2. The colors should indicate be `green` for correctly predicated part and `red` for incorrectly predicated part

How can I solve this?

---

Any help also in *simplified approaches* is appreciated..

Comment: I have upvoted both answers but they both forget the second part of the question, add `scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "green"))`.

Comment: just use `scale_fill_manual(values = c("FALSE"="red","TRUE"= "green"))`

Comment: Hi @RuiBarradas-ReinstateMonic, thanks for pointing it out. I was thinking about that. Just wondering whether OP meant red / green as in the orange / green in the plot showed or "red" / "green" as defined by R. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, geom_bar() does count for stats, meaning it counts the number of TRUE/FALSE, which gives 1:1. So you can use geom_col() or geom_bar(stat="identity") instead

Try something like this:

```
g <- data.frame(conf[,1:2]) %>% 
tibble::rownames_to_column("observed") %>% 
pivot_longer(-observed,names_to = "predicted") %>% 
ggplot() + geom_col(aes(x=observed,y=value,fill=predicted))
print(g)
```

[image: plot]

For really red / green:

```
#set the colors
# note you have FALSE. and TRUE. in your matrix
COLS = c("TRUE."="green","FALSE."="red")
g + scale_fill_manual(values = COLS)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Load packages

```
library(tidyverse)
```

Then this is your matrix.

```
conf <- structure(c(3015, 672, 874, 3217, 0.224736436101826, 0.1727950629982
), .Dim = 2:3, .Dimnames = list(c("FALSE", "TRUE"), c("FALSE", 
                                                      "TRUE", "class.error")))

conf %>% # take the matrix then
    as.data.frame() %>% # convert it into a dataframe
    select(-class.error) %>% # remove the class.error column
    mutate(actual = rownames(.)) %>% # make the rownames a column
    gather(key = "predicted", value = "obs", -actual) %>% # put the data into a long format
    ggplot(aes(actual, obs, fill = predicted)) + # plot with these aesthetics
    geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

The `stat = "identity"` part is important, since `ggplot` is otherwise looking for the number of rows, but you want the number **in** the rows.